# jQuery horizontal navigation issue with widths as %

Tags: jquery

Im using jQuery so that choosing an option from a select list horizontally scrolls a div to the appropriate content within it. Each div that you scroll to should take up 100% of the page's visible width.

http://jsfiddle.net/jamesbrighton/KUMqV/6/

My design will have a liquid width, so Ive used % values for the width not pixels. I think the issue is that the % calculations are slightly off. For the first option 'may' the div takes up the full width like I need it to. As you look at the other options, the further through the list you go the shorter the div are.

This functionality cant be that rare so id really appreciate any thoughts on how to solve this when the number of options arn't a nice round number like 10. Thanks

UPDATE Here is a picture of what I mean. The red border should be 100% width but its less. [image]

Comment: Width seems ok even after a few option changes here in FF12.

Comment: Ive updated my question with a image showing the issue.

Comment: Actually your right, its not happening in FF but it is in Chrome and Safari. The focus of my site is iPhone and Android users so it defiantly needs to work in webkit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/KUMqV/23/ 
not the cleanest solution, but by adding 4 extra divs, you can set the width to 1600% and 6,25%.
Greetings, Gijoey

Comment: Works, but is there a more semantic way if I was rebuilding from scratch?

Comment: I don't think so. It's because of subpixel rounding. Browsers behave very differently on this matter. Have a look at this article: http://ejohn.org/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/

Comment: I think in future I might experiment with using absolute positioning instead of floating. Then the container width could stay as 100% so it would only need to be moved + or - 100% each time. Ill need to make it to be sure, but I think this should work. Thanks